# Google Gmail rejects my friend's MX records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, google, gmail, mx-record

My friend has some problem with Google Apps Gmail, his MX records got rejected. We're trying to resolve the issue somehow, but with no success so far. We've googled the whole world (this site too) but got nothing.

The given domain is d2racing-sport.hu

```
bash-3.2$ host d2racing-sport.hu
d2racing-sport.hu has address 88.151.101.225
d2racing-sport.hu has IPv6 address 2a01:270:2015::2
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
d2racing-sport.hu mail is handled by 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
bash-3.2$
```

Google tells it needs 48 hours to check, when it passed tells that the MX record setup is wrong. We cannot find a problem about them though.

We tried to have only one MX record: aspmx.l.google.com. No success this way. We're running out of time... Maybe we just cannot see something, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Those MXes look OK to me.  Do you have the authentication CNAME in place as well?  Forgetting that makes the Googleplex sad.

Comment: No auth CNAMEs are there, only email.* CNAMEs to redirect to webmail.

Comment: That's your problem, then.  Add the auth CNAME that Google tells you to use, and all will be well.

Comment: Yeah. In my experience, once you have the CNAME entry that Google requests you add, you'll be validated very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the aspmx4 and aspmx5 entries before (but google does have then in DNS so they are probably good.)  It might be that you have aspmx2-5 all with the same MX priority of 30.  Google's generic instructions are:

- 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
- 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
- 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
- 10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
- 10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33915

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We'll try this list too, but every other apps domains work with either the main server address only or the +2 address too. It's weird. Maybe they just changed the rules to this list. I don't think that it's the problem though... but we try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
aspmx.1.google.com
```

should be be:

```
aspmx.google.com
```

That's the only problem I can see